# web2py How to add id to submit_button

Tags: javascript, jquery, web2py

In my html file, I'm adding two forms, each with their own submit_button. I have a text input in one of the forms and want to make it required to be not blank but it doesn't seem to work...

```
userQueryForm = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('userQuery', label='', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY() ), 
    submit_button = T('Generate Report')
    )
```

The html that gets rendered is as follows

```
<td class="w2p_fw">
    <input class="string" id="no_table_userQuery" name="userQuery" type="text" value="">
</td>
...
<tr id="submit_record__row">
    <td class="w2p_fl"></td>
    <td class="w2p_fw">
       <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" class="btn">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want my `<input>` to have an id so i can access it in Jquery...

My ultimate goal is to not allow the form to be subitted if the text

Answer (score 0):

You can access the submit button server-side DOM element via `userQueryForm.custom.submit`, so to add an `id` attribute:

```
userQueryForm.custom.submit.update(_id='submit_button')
```

Alternatively, there are other methods to access the submit button via jQuery rather than relying on an `id`. For example:

```
jQuery('input[value="Generate Report"]')
```